How to Compare Discrete and Continuous Lorenz System Solutions
I wrote the following code to solve the discrete form of the Lorenz system. I would like to compare this result from the table the code below generated, with a simular table derived for the continuous Lorenz system solution using NDSolve. Thoughts or suggestions are most appreciated.
Clear["Global`*"]
NN = 20; x0 = 0; y0 = 1; z0 = 0; a = 10; b = 8/3; r = 28; dt = 0.01;
{tmin, tmax} = {0, NN};
N[TableForm[MapThread[Prepend, {RecurrenceTable[{
      x[t + 1] == x[t] + a*(y[t] - x[t])*dt,
      y[t + 1] == y[t] + (r*x[t] - x[t]*z[t] - y[t])*dt,
      z[t + 1] == z[t] + (x[t]*y[t] - b*z[t])*dt,
      x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0, z[0] == z0}, {x, y, z}, {t, tmin, 
      tmax}], Range[tmin, tmax]}], 
  TableHeadings -> {None, {"t", "x[t]", "y[t]", "z[t]"}}]]


pts = RecurrenceTable[{x[t + 1] == x[t] + a*(y[t] - x[t])*dt, 
    y[t + 1] == y[t] + (r*x[t] - x[t]*z[t] - y[t])*dt, 
    z[t + 1] == z[t] + (x[t]*y[t] - b*z[t])*dt, x[0] == x0, 
    y[0] == y0, z[0] == z0}, {x, y, z}, {t, tmin, tmax}];
g3 = Graphics3D[{Thick, Red, Dashed, Arrow[pts]}];
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == +a*(y[t] - x[t]), 
    y'[t] == (r*x[t] - x[t]*z[t] - y[t]), 
    z'[t] == (x[t]*y[t] - b*z[t]), x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0, 
    z[0] == z0}, {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, 20}];
pp = ParametricPlot3D[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, 0.20}, 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Thin, White}];
Show[pp, g3, Background -> Black]



wonderful work! ... thank you
